# Permission Denied on ./vcpkg install

Tags: macos, wxwidgets, vcpkg

Has anyone encountered this error before with vcpkg? I'm running MacOS. To install vcpkg I ran:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg

...

./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh

...

./vcpkg integrate install

zsh: permission denied: ./vcpkg
```

Also trying to run:

```
./vcpkg install wxwidgets

zsh: permission denied: ./vcpkg
```

Comment: you should run it as `Administrator` or with the `sudo`

Comment: if i run ./vcpkg sudo integrate install it still says permission denied. Am i typing that correctly? sudo ./vcpkg install wxwidgets and ./vcpkg command not found

Comment: ah i looked at the directory and i think i was just running the code from the wrong directory

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it needs to be executed from the `/bin` directory and not from the `/vcpkg` directory. so that means (if you used brew to install it, otherwise it'll be somewhere else) ⤵︎

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/vcpkg/2020.11-1/bin
```

*(just open a file explorer window and find the bin folder in `vcpkg`, you can then copy the path name and use that for your cd command, or open a shell window at that directory)*

Then all you have to do is simply run the original command ⤵︎

```
$ ./vcpkg integrate install
```